# Ajax loaded nested list Can't get event from inner

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

We have this nested list:

```
   <ul id="AllTopics" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search topic...">
            <li><a href="#">Polite Phrases</a><span class="ui-li-count">101</span>
              <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
                <li ><a href="#Main" data-parm="Polite Phrases">Polite Phrases</a><span class="ui-li-count">101</span></li>
                <li ><a href="#Main" data-parm="Polite Phrases">At The End Of A Letter/Email</a><span class="ui-li-count">101</span></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
   </ul>
```

The first `<ul>` with the id="AllTopics" is in the html documnet itself,

The inner `<li><ul><li>...` are loaded from Ajax call like:

```
on('pageinit'... event
             ...   $("ul").append(...
```

I can get the event from the first new born `<li>` , like:

```
$('#AllTopics').on('click','li',function (event){...
```

But the inner `<li>` or `<a>` do not seem to fire events :-(

Ani ideas ?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be that the new content is loaded using an Ajax call, and you just setup the events before, so the new elements won't have them.

Try using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) JQuery function:

```
$('#AllTopics').delegate('li a','click',function(){
   alert('How you dare to click on my links?!');
});
```

**EDIT**

Other solution is to assign the events once elements are added via Ajax call.

```
// This is an example, retrieve the data on your own form
$.get('mypage.php',function(data){
   // Add content to your DOM elements
   $('#AllTopics').append(data);

   // Assign events
   $('#AllTopics').on('click','li',function (event){
      alert('Holy moly, you keep clicking on my links!');
   });
});
```

**Note**: I just realized that your HTML elements have this composition:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a/>
   </li>
   <span/>
   <ul>
      <li>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

So, OF COURSE that is only affecting the first one because there are two levels of `li - a` (you have an `ul` element inside another one). You can define an `ID` for your second group of `li - a` elements to trigger events successfully or keep doing it in this way:

```
$('#AllTopics').delegate('li a','click',function(){
   alert('How you dare to click on the first link?!');
});

$('#AllTopics').delegate('ul li a','click',function(){
   alert('Stop clicking my children links!');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, doe's it meen that if I wait long time I will get the events?

Comment: The problem is that you are adding content to your page after all the events are already set. Wait for them is not a good design decision, so I recommend you to do something like I said in order to avoid future issues :)

Comment: What about trying to set up the events once your elements are added? Something like I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Tried the last one too but,,, :-(
Maybe something like:
    $.get("Get_Categories_list.php", function (data) {
             $("#AllTopics").append(data).listview('refresh',function{

Comment: I beleave using pagebeforcreate event to load and set the html list dinamically will work,
I don't realy need to dinamically change the list while my app's running